# How to work with a uploaded JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json, file-upload, leaflet

I have a leaflet map and I want to enable users to input json files and visualize those.

I managed to import a local JSON file with the following code

```
  $.getJSON('CompleteList.json', function (geojson) {
  jsonlayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
    }
  }).addTo(map);
```

I think it would be too much to post all my code so im just gonna post a pic of the html as it is now.
[image: Current html]

the upload field is

```
<input type='file' accept='json' onchange='loadFile(event)'>
```

My question is, how do i "catch" the file once i pressed the button and save it as a variable so that i can use the above AJAX code. Or is it not possible to use that here?

Comment: See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/